# character entity converting to character when I want it left as an entity in Arbortext

Tags: xml, entity, special-characters

I have an original XML code that includes an entity

```
<technumber>1&amp;P</technumber>
```

When this is opened in Arbortext I get `1&P` instead. when I want it left as the entity. is there a setting I can use to keep this conversion from happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arbortext has an advanced preference "entityinputconvert" turn it off.